# uncaught exception: creating web worker thread

Tags: javascript, web-worker

I am doing a simple worker instantiation using the code below.  I realized while versioning the code that an error is not thrown if the javascript file is not valid for the constructor.  I am using Chrome.  the onerror and the try catch both do not get executed and the thread does nothing when the postMessage is executed.  Is there something I am missing? (the file location is purposely wrong in this example and I am using Chrome version 31.0.1650.63 m)

```
try {
        //var target = document.getElementById("spinner");
        OpenDialogProgress("...Validating Creditials, please wait...");

        //Start Web Worker thread
        window.userWorker = new Worker('/Scripts//UserWorker-1.0.1.js');

        window.userWorker.addEventListener('message', function (e) {
            SiteManager.processUserCreditialMessage(e.data);
        }, false);

        window.userWorker.onerror = function (event) {
            var Error = new Error(event.message);
            Error.stack = event.lineno;
            HandleError.processJavaScriptError(Error, "userWorker error", event.filename);
            window.userWorker.terminate();
        };

        window.userWorker.postMessage({ 'cmd': 'validateServerCreditials', 'username': username, 'password': password, 'wsTimeout': Configure.WebServiceTimeout });
    }
    catch (error) {
        HandleError.processJavaScriptError(error, "userWorker error", SiteManager.TypeCode);
        window.userWorker.terminate();
    }
```

Comment: Are you getting an exception or not? If so, what is it?

Comment: No exceptions.  The onerror does NOT execute and the catch is NOT executed.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out to be a syntax error in the location of the worker thread:
new Worker('needs to be a valid uri');

The painful part was that Javascript didn't complain.